# May the translation-function set with _set_se_translator just return without throwing?

Tags: winapi

May the translation-function set with `_set_se_translator` just return without throwing?

If so, would this mean that the further processing goes the way of normal SEH-processing?

[EDIT]: I tried it out myself:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    _set_se_translator( []( unsigned int, EXCEPTION_POINTERS * ) { } );
    __try
    {
        RaiseException( EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR, 0, 0, nullptr );
    }
    __except( EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER )
    {
        cout << "caught" << endl;
    }
}
```

Is this specified to work?

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-se-translator?view=msvc-170) (added emphasis mine):

> Your translator function ***should do no more than throw a C++ typed
> exception***. If it does anything in addition to throwing (such as
> writing to a log file, for example) your program might not behave as
> expected because the number of times the translator function is
> invoked is platform-dependent.

If we take this completely literally, then a translator function should not return, as this is doing something 'more' than throwing a typed exception. However, I can find no *specific* mention in that document (or any related ones) that the function should *never* return, and neither does the function's prototype specify the `[[noreturn]]` attribute (though that, in itself, may not mean very much).

Comment: `[[noreturn]]` was introduced with C++11, so it's unlikely to be present in any compiler support header files. The MSVC-specific attribute is `__declspec(noreturn)`. Though I'm not sure whether either one is part of the function signature, and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/noreturn) isn't helpful here. So absence of this attribute may or may not mean anything.

Comment: Thanks for that but I think the function should do that at last. Simply throwing an exception witout evaluating the exception code or the information passed with the EXCEPTION_POINTERS woudln't make sense for me.

Comment: Another issue is the fact that your translation function will be called asynchronously (because you should be using the `/EHa` compiler flag). The ramifications of that when your function returns are ... weird??

Comment: @AdrianMole: I simply had the hope that if the translator doesn't throw depending on the given parameters normal SEH processing would take place. That would give a nice to have feature.

Comment: @BonitaMontero But, in a real-world translator, which may either throw a C++ exception or just return (potentially propagating the structured exception), how would your thread code be written to catch either the C++ or the structured exception? Would you have a `try {...} catch() {}` block nested inside a `__try{...} __except{...}` ?

Comment: @AdrianMole: You might catch the SEH-exception locally and the C++-exception above in the call-graph.